# Quarter wave transformer

Tags: transmission

I appreciate help on a confusion regarding a quarter wave transformer.

When reflections at the feed-line on a transmission line are eliminated, how is all the power absorbed by the load when there are still reflections at the transformer, since the impedance (Z<sub>02</sub> in the diagram) is still not the same as the load impedance?

[image: illustration here]

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that 10% of the power is reflected from the load, since the 1/4 wave lines are lossless, all of that power will then be reflected back from AA' towards the load again, the load will reflect 10% of that, so now there will be 1% of the original power reflected, and that will come back to the load, where it reflects 0.1% of the original power, repeat until all (effectively) of the power ends up in the load.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My main question is, why would the same power be reflected back at AA'?

Answer (score 0):

If the "reflections" bother you somewhat, just use a matching "exponential" line...which will have the advantage of being broadband.